# Print any type of data (int, char etc) in binary form

Tags: c

I was wondering if we can print the binary form of any type of data ,i.e., it's 0's and 1's form (i think we can say that it's machine language form) using existing methods in c.

Or will i have to do it myself by defining a function myself that converts it in that form?

Also it will be helpful if anybody can tell me where can i ask questions about working on a project(like compression etc) from people who can guide me what to do?

Comment: You're actually asking how to print a number in base 2.

Comment: Yes and if possible answer the project question also?
Thanks for the fast reply.

Comment: [Duplicate?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/111928/is-there-a-printf-converter-to-print-in-binary-format)

Comment: @Karolis Juodele 
Ok thanx but can i get an answer for the project related question too?

Answer (score 0):

You may use the [itoa](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/itoa/) function. It converts integers to string with specific base:

```
itoa(num, string, 2);
```

Comment: Although `itoa` doesn't exist on all platforms, you would probably have to write your own function if you wanted to be portable.